# M. Riesz's Theorem for $L^2(T)$

Tags: complex-analysis, hardy-spaces

Suppose that $f \in L^2(T)$ and define
\begin{equation}
F(z)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_T \frac{e^{it}+z}{e^{it}-z} f(e^{it}) dt
\end{equation} for $z \in U$. M. Riesz's Theorem states that there exists a constant $C_2$ such that $\|F\|_2 \le C_2\|f\|_2$. I wonder whether we can apply the Parseval Theorem to prove this result and find the best value of $C_2$. Unfortunately, I don't know how to start. Any suggestion?

Comment: Note that the kernel is the sum of a geometric series. Substitute that series and you get the power series for $F$; now you can use Parseval...

Comment: I think may be you can use the Riesz-Fischer theorem in chapter 4 of rudin's RCA

Answer (score 1):

Let
$$
P(z, e^{it}) = \frac{e^{it}+z}{e^{it}-z}
$$

$$\frac{1}{2\pi} \int_T |F(re^{i\theta})|^2 d\theta = \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_T |\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_T P(re^{i\theta}, e^{it}) f(e^{it}) dt|^2 d\theta$$

$$
<\frac{1}{2\pi} \int_T |\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_T |P(re^{i\theta}, e^{it}) f(e^{it})| dt|^2 d\theta
$$
Schwarz inequality
$$
< \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_T \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_T |P(re^{i\theta}, e^{it})|^2 dt] ||f||_2d\theta
$$
$$
< ||f||_2\frac{1}{2\pi} \int_T\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_T |P(re^{i\theta}, e^{it})|^2 dt d\theta 
$$
$$
C_2 = inf_{0\leq r < 1} \int_T\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_T |P(re^{i\theta}, e^{it})|^2 dt d\theta 
$$